# No funciona una macro de google sheet. Quiero ordenar una hoja por una columna específica

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy trabajando en una planilla de Google sheet. La misma esta ordenada por columnas con datos de personas, primero nombre, DNI y fecha de ingreso del dato.

Cree una macro para que estos se ordenen por la fecha de ingreso, el tema es que en la computadora funciona perfectamente pero cuando entro desde el celular no se ejecuta y tira este error ¨ ***Las combinaciones deben estar completamente en el rango que se desea ordenar.*** ¨

Este archivo tiene varias hojas (algunas involucran hasta la columna p) y solo quiero ordenar una sola (Llega hasta columna h) no se si ese será el problema.

Copio ejemplo:

```
function Ordenar() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A:H').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(1, 0, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows() - 1).sort({column: 5, ascending: true});
};
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Cómo estás llamando el script desde el móvil? ¿Estás usando un navegador o la app de Hojas de Cálculo de Google? P.S. Te sugiero siempre que sea posible evitar el uso del rango activo.

Comment: Uso la app de hojas de cálculo de Google, nunca entre desde el navegador. Cómo evito usar el rango activo? Podrías decirme una alternativa? Gracias

Comment: Asigna `spreadsheet.getRange('A:H')` a una variable y úsala en lugar de `spreadsheet.getActiveRange()`. Si requieres mayor orientación [edit] la pregunta para agregar a esta todos los detalles relevantes como los pasos que sigues para ejecutar la macro en la app, así como las características relevantes de las hojas tanto en las que ocurre el error como en las que no.